# How to mock Document.getElementById in react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-testing-library

I am using headless UI `Dialog, Transition` component and i am getting this below error while writing test case `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementById')` using react testing library so how do i mock Document.getElementByID in React testing library?

```
describe('Testing  Component', () => {
  test('It should render component', () => {
    render(
      <Edit
        form={form}
        phoneNumber={phoneNumber}
        appId={appId}
      />,
    );
    const isItRendered = screen.getByTestId('lending_editAPP');
    expect(isItRendered).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please show the minimal, complete code under test

Comment: Can you please share your component code?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but might be helpful for starter’s.

In order to use getByTestId, you need to have the **data-testid** on the tag you want to select from the react component. for e.g.

```
const MyComponent = ()=>{
    return (
       <section>
           <p data-testid="lending_editAPP"> some text</p>
       <section>
    )
```

Then you can select the p tag using the following code and perform the necessary testing.

```
const p_tag = screen.getByTestId('lending_editAPP');
```

**Note :**
It is not recommended to use testId to select element. As react testing library is meant to be used for testing component with least or no change in the actual source code. Additionally, you can use extension like [testing-playground](https://testing-playground.com/) to get better queries to select a particular element.

you can refer this for more details on queries.
[React testing library - byTestId](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid)